# How to check all the values of a specific field in an XML using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have this payload

```
<Order>
  <Id>8017Z000001Ks6zQAC</Id>
  <CreatedById>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</CreatedById>
  <OwnerId>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</OwnerId>
  <CreatedBy>
   <Name>Sharmila Test Account</Name>
   <Email>shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa</Email>
   <Profile>
    <Name>Customer Community Plus User</Name>
   </Profile>
  </CreatedBy>
  <SalesStore>
   <Name>ShopVestas</Name>
  </SalesStore>
 </Order>
<Order>
  <Id>8017Z000002dfBBQAY</Id>
  <CreatedById>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</CreatedById>
  <OwnerId>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</OwnerId>
  <CreatedBy>
   <Name>Sharmila Test Account</Name>
   <Email>shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa</Email>
   <Profile>
    <Name>Customer Community Plus User</Name>
   </Profile>
  </CreatedBy>
  <SalesStore>
   <Name>ShopVestas</Name>
  </SalesStore>
 </Order>
```

Is it possible to check each Email field and compare it with a String? I have this code but it is not working as I what I intended as my condition is not being satisfied at all even if the String that I want to compare exists

```
   def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String)
   def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(body)
   
   if(xml.Order.Createdby.Email=="shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa")
   {
       message.setProperty("userInit", "jeremy.irigayen@gmail.com");
   }
   else
   {
       message.setProperty("userInit", "jjmii@vestas.com");
   }

   return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a parent node  to your sample. This produes a list, that you can do with what you want. Please take the time to read [the documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) so that you can understand how it works and what options there are.

```
def xml = '''
<sample>
<Order>
  <Id>8017Z000001Ks6zQAC</Id>
  <CreatedById>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</CreatedById>
  <OwnerId>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</OwnerId>
  <CreatedBy>
   <Name>Sharmila Test Account</Name>
   <Email>shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa</Email>
   <Profile>
    <Name>Customer Community Plus User</Name>
   </Profile>
  </CreatedBy>
  <SalesStore>
   <Name>ShopVestas</Name>
  </SalesStore>
 </Order>
<Order>
  <Id>8017Z000002dfBBQAY</Id>
  <CreatedById>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</CreatedById>
  <OwnerId>0057Z000008KzAtQAK</OwnerId>
  <CreatedBy>
   <Name>Sharmila Test Account</Name>
   <Email>shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa</Email>
   <Profile>
    <Name>Customer Community Plus User</Name>
   </Profile>
  </CreatedBy>
  <SalesStore>
   <Name>ShopVestas</Name>
  </SalesStore>
 </Order>
</sample>
'''

def sample = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def emails = sample.'**'.findAll { node -> node.name() == 'Email' }
assert emails == ['shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa', 'shnielsen@deloitte.dk.vestasqa']
```